# MacBook (mid-2012) stuck on white screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra, internet-recovery

So I casually shut down my MacBook on Thursday night using the normal configuration. After a while when I switched it back on, a white screen appeared and that was the end of it. Later, a black screen appeared and asked me to hit Ctrl+Alt+Delete, but upon pressing those keys nothing happened, so then I restarted my laptop in Internet Recovery Mode from where I deleted my Windows OS from the BootCamp and then tried reinstalling the Mac OS (Yosemite).  The installation progress happens just fine until it gets to the last 3 minutes, where the progress bar gets stuck. Upon checking the Installer Log, it seems like the computer keeps running into various kinds of errors such as: "Could not find package ref", and "Chunk download failed, retrying". I left my laptop overnight to continue with the progress, and the installation was just stuck. HELP!!!!

P.S. I was running High Sierra and Windows 10 prior to this issue.

Comment: If you have access to another Mac it might be worth downloading High Sierra and moving it to an external drive and install from it. See this [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372) article